# How to rowspan dynamic, group and merge same name record?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

How to rowspan dynamic, group and merge same name record?

I have an ASP.NET MVC project, in dynamic view page, I need rowspan if is same Name in column.

This is default grouped view without rowspan:

[image]

I have this markup in my view:

```
@{ 
    var datax = Model as IEnumerable<WebLoginComp.Models.tbl_insSignale>;
    int perferenceNo = 1;
}

@foreach (var itemX in datax.GroupBy(s => s.tbl_Devices.devName))
{
    foreach (var item in itemX)
    {
        int LSCount = datax.Count(x => x.devID == item.devID);

        var LSName = datax.Count(x => x.tbl_Devices.devID == item.devID);
     <tr>
         @if (LSCount != perferenceNo)
         {
             perferenceNo = LSCount;
             <td rowspan="@LSCount">@item.tbl_Devices.devName</td>

         }
         else
         {
             <td>@item.tbl_Devices.devName</td>          
         }
         <td>@item.date</td>
         <td>@item.status</td>
         <td>@item.info</td>
         <td>@item.date</td>
         <td>@item.uID</td>
    </tr>
    }
}
```

After `rowspan="@LSCount"` is added, I have this view:

[image]

How to get table as on next Image?

[image]

What is wrong here, and how to merge same name cells at **Signal Nr** column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the `else` branch

```
@if (LSCount != perferenceNo)
{
    perferenceNo = LSCount;
    <td rowspan="@LSCount">@item.tbl_Devices.devName</td>
}

<td>@item.date</td>
<td>@item.status</td>
<td>@item.info</td>
<td>@item.date</td>
<td>@item.uID</td>
```